# Add a shortcut to a different home screen?

Tags: home-screen

Is there a way that I can add a shortcut to another home screen?

What I'm aiming for is having my primary home screen that includes a shortcut to various topical home screens where I can have both widgets and app shortcuts.

Adding a number of home screens in this manner makes it difficult to navigate, which is why I'd like to add shortcuts to them.

For example, right now my primary home screen has a finance folder and a social media folder, etc that each contain app shortcuts. I then have a separate home screen that has a couple finance widgets on it, another home screen that has a couple widgets from my social media apps, etc. I am not using as many widgets as I'd like because I don't want to have to scroll through home screens to get to the widget I want.

My goal is to have my primary home screen contain a shortcut that goes to a home screen that has my finance widgets and app shortcuts, as well as another shortcut on the primary home screen that goes to a different home screen containing my social media widgets and app shortcuts, and so on.

(I'm using a non-rooted Samsung Galaxy Edge running 4.4.4.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might work with specific "Launchers" which support a direct "go to screen X" (not all launchers do). A launcher that *does* support this is [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher), even in its free version:

[image: Apex Actions Screenshot] [image: Apex Shortcut Edit]
<sup>Screenshot of *Apex* actions and shortcut edit (click images for larger variants)</sup>

On the homescreen, press an empty space as if to add a widget/shortcut. From the popup, select "Apex Actions" ("Apex-Aktionen" in the screenshot). Scroll to the end of the list (red box in the screenshot), and you find a shortcut to each of your homescreens.

Note that after having selected the screen you want to link to (say, "Screen 1"), the link will be immediately created as shown and with the name "Screen 1" – which probably is not exactly what you had in mind. But we're not done yet: Long-tap (tap-and-hold) the new icon on your homescreen, until a context menu appears. From that, select "edit" – and you should see something similar to the second screenshot. Here you not only can change the description shown below the icon, but even the icon itself – to e.g. replace it by a coin for your "financial screen". You can chose from "standard symbols" included, and also from your own pictures.

Enjoy :)